# Adding user input to ArrayList using do-while loop

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

I am trying to add user input to an Arraylist using a do-while loop however I keep ending up with a list consisting of only the final item inputed repeated several times.

```
public static ArrayList<Item> purchaseItems()
       {
        ArrayList<Item> toBuy = new ArrayList<Item>();

        String response;
        System.out.println("What would you like to purchase? (type \"done\" to end) ");   
        do {

             response = in.nextLine();
             if(!response.equals("done") ){

                    toBuy.add(new Item(response, randGen.nextInt(100)));
                    System.out.println(toBuy);
            }

        } while(!response.equals("done"));

        return toBuy;
    }
```

Comment: Include the Item class in your question

Comment: you need to iterate through your list if you want to print ALL the items in your list

Comment: it works for me. please share your whole code, or tell us/me how do you assume that the List contains only duplicates

Comment: Are your fields in `Item` perhaps `static`?

Comment: Oh yeah, the fields were static, that fixed it. thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

should work as mentioned in my comment.
Please implement a toString() method in your Item class if not done already.
you should replace your System.out.println as following:

```
    public static ArrayList<Item> purchaseItems()
           {
            ArrayList<Item> toBuy = new ArrayList<Item>();

            String response;
            System.out.println("What would you like to purchase? (type \"done\" to end) ");   
            do {

                 response = in.nextLine();
                 if(!response.equals("done") ){

                        toBuy.add(new Item(response, randGen.nextInt(100)));
                }

            } while(!response.equals("done"));

               for (Item item : toBuy){
               System.out.println(item);
                }
            return toBuy;
        }
```

if this doesn't helps, please share some more code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is fully working example

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q53837506 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Item> purchaseItems = purchaseItems();
        System.out.println(purchaseItems);

    }

    public static class Item {
        String r;
        int v;

        public Item(String r, int v) {
            super();
            this.r = r;
            this.v = v;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Item [r=" + r + ", v=" + v + "]";
        }
    }

    static final Random randGen = new Random();

    public static ArrayList<Item> purchaseItems() {
        ArrayList<Item> toBuy = new ArrayList<Item>();

        String response;
        System.out.println("What would you like to purchase? (type \"done\" to end) ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {

            response = in.nextLine();
            if (!response.equals("done")) {

                toBuy.add(new Item(response, randGen.nextInt(100)));
                System.out.println(toBuy);
            }
        } while (!response.equals("done"));

        return toBuy;
    }
}
```